# How to open MX Player with ADB?

Tags: android, adb

Can we open MX Player on Android using ADB?

With command similar to:

`adb shell am start -n com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad/... -d file:///sdcard/video.mp4`

Just to clarify, not looking for the general command:

`adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d file:///sdcard/video.mp4 -t video/mp4`

Answer (score 0):

```
adb shell am start -n com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad/com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad.ActivityScreen -d file:///sdcard/1.mp4
```